# How to initialize a minimum value for a user defined struct in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-map

This is my user defined struct

```
struct Data
    {
        int value;
        int age;
    };
```

I am defining a function to get the maximum value in an unordered_map.

```
unordered_map<int,Data>::iterator maxValue(unordered_map<int, Data> map) {
    pair<int, Data> entryWithMaxValue = make_pair(INT_MIN, ??);
}
```

What should I write in place of the question mark so as to define a minimum value for type Data?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in place of your `??`:

```
Data{INT_MIN, INT_MIN}
```

You could also use `Data{}` to get zero for value and age if you prefer.  In truth it doesn't matter, because the maximum value of an empty container is not well defined.

Comment: What do you mean by "the maximum value of an empty container is not well defined"?

Comment: @Ayxan: What is the largest integer in an empty set of integers?